# How to use schema in DMBS SAS connection

Tags: sql-server, sas, odbc

Below script show me table dbo.calendar in SAS:

```
LIBNAME SQL ODBC DSN='sql server' ;

PROC PRINT DATA=SQL.calendar;
RUN;
```

When I changed *DATA* to *SQL.dbo.calendar* (this is a correct name from SQL Server), I got:

```
6032  PROC PRINT DATA=SQL.dbo.calendar;
ERROR: Invalid data set name SQL.dbo.calendar.
```

Why and how to choose other schemas in SAS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default schema is defined in the DSN.  Use the `SCHEMA=` option in the `LIBNAME` Statement

```
LIBNAME SQL ODBC DSN='sql server' schema=<something other than default> ;
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/69039/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0bu3zsz1a08ton1msxdx1jo45np.htm